# CSS relative-path background image not showing

Tags: php, css

Using NetBeans IDE 8.2, the image will not load if called in the css file when running the project in firefox. I have started a PHP project and my file system is

```
Project Folder
    -Source Files
        -images
            -image.jpg
        -styles
            -style.css
        index.php
    -Include Path
```

as shown in my IDE (I am new to Netbeans). The css code:

```
.bgimg-1 { 
    background-image: url("../images/image.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and PHP snippet

```
<head>      
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WEBSITE TITLE</title>
    <link href="styles/style.css?v=0.0.4" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles/homepage.css?v=0.0.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles/header-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <!-- Background image -->
    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="display-middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
             <span class="center padding-large black text-xlarge wide 10-opacity"> WEBSITE NAME </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried various urls including

```
("CD ../images/image.jpg")
("images/image.jpg")
("/images/image.jpg")
```

The css file is linked correctly as when I change background color it works. I also know that this works in brackets and that the image is present in folder as when called in html file it shows. I am very confused please help. I must add this is a local host
Project Folder : C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBSITE-PHP with this being the source folder and web root

Comment: What does your browser's _Network_ console say about the request for the image? What URL is it resolving to? What is the response?

Comment: FYI, `("CD ...")` is **never** a valid path for a CSS `url()` declaration

Comment: Network console image status 305. Yeah I was at a loose end. and in browser console 'Image corrupt or truncated. URI in this note truncated due to length.'

Comment: can you try using some other images and see if it renders?

Comment: I've just tried a much smaller png file with no success

Comment: Have you tried already using "./images/image.jpg" for the source?

Comment: The status code '305' you are getting is for Proxy, which means you need to use a proxy to access those data. But I am not sure why you get that status code. I think you might need to look the folder permission or server configuration.

Comment: yes "./images/image.jpg" has already been tried the strange thing is that I can load the image using <img src=BLAH>etc in php file it will load but when in style sheet it does not load

Comment: in chrome i receive a status 200. If it is the folder permissions how do I change these?

Comment: can you try:
`.bgimg-1 { 
    background: url("../images/image.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
    height: 100px;
    background-size:cover;
}`

Comment: I'm sorry nothing new

Comment: I would try a basic placeholder.it image to test the stylesheet first. Example: http://via.placeholder.com/350x150

Comment: If there any warnings or errors in console?

Comment: Do you try to get image directly? is there .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Was actually a really simple fix and a problem with my knowledge of DOCTYPEs. I was using DOCTYPE html. However, the html5 or xml DOCTYPE is needed for the use of a parallax background image.